# SQL update using its update information

Tags: sql, oracle

With the goals to optimize queries in a legacy application, I came across the following query which aims to update the Materialized Path of hierarchical data.

```sql
UPDATE data child
            SET child.MATERIALIZED_PATH = CONCAT((
               SELECT parent.MATERIALIZED_PATH FROM data parent 
               WHERE child.PARENT_ID = parent.OBJECT_ID
            ), CONCAT('/', object_id))
            WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT * FROM data parent 
            WHERE child.PARENT_ID = parent.OBJECT_ID);
```

This empirically works and is coupled with another trivial query to set the roots (which paths are the nodes themselves).

This query is by far the fastest of the other methods I tried (RBAR is obviously slow, I was expecting better from a recursive CTE but it still is about 6x slower).
I can see in the query plan why this is faster and from the looks of it, it can't be further optimized.

What I do not understand is why this works without "explicit recursion". Setting the `MATERIALIZED_PATH`'s value looks like it is only taking into account and concatenating two levels, the parent and the child.

It is obvious that if the parent has already gone through the update, it will be correct, and the query can use its value. But what if the update took a row for which the parent has not been updated? then the parent's value would be incorrect, propagating this incorrect value to the child. Why doesn't this happen? Why is Oracle smart enough to update the values in a hierarchical fashion, which I would guess has nothing to do with a hierarchy, but is simply updating rows using rows that will not receive further updates.

I'd like to know more about this feature so that I can read about it, because had I not seen that legacy query, I wouldn't have known this was an option.

Comment: There's no predefined order of row processing, so it's a kind of luck. Please provide reproducible example to demonstrate what you observe.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b5705cb0802d78c5833989ced1f10f3a

Comment: Ow, thanks. If you're right then there is an error in the current query. I'll look into it and to provide an example if I can have it consistently working

Comment: Thank you both, the query is indeed false and that explains a lot. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments (thank you!), there is no predefined order of row processing, and the kindly provided fiddle directly shows the script's output is incorrect.

The question is void since it was based on a false assumption. The snippet produces incorrect data. This also explains why the algorithm is faster, since there is no recursion involved.